# Using dynamic property value in OnlineResource href against MongoDB store?

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, ogc

I am passing this SLD to geoserver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
<NamedLayer>
    <Name>cite:test</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Test</Title>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
          <Rule>
            <PointSymbolizer>
              <Graphic>
                <ExternalGraphic>
                  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost/icons/river"/>
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>35</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

That works great, but will get the my 'river' icon for ever feature.  Say there is a property called icon.type in for the data source that lives behind this layer.  Is there a way to use the value of that property for each features OnlineResource?  In that way I would only have to define one PointSymbolizer.

IE, something like this:

```
<ExternalGraphic>
  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost/icons/{icon.type}"/>
  <Format>image/png</Format>
</ExternalGraphic>
```

**EDIT:**

Turns out you can indeed use a dynamic property by using CQL in the url:

```
<ExternalGraphic>
  <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost/icons/${icon.type}"/>
  <Format>image/png</Format>
</ExternalGraphic>
```

However I am using a mongodb store and the extension does not seem to query the backend mongo store correctly for that property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got pretty close to the actual syntax (it's a GeoServer extension mind, not part of the OGC standards):
http://blog.geoserver.org/2008/12/08/dynamic-symbolizers-part-1/

Comment: thanks!  I am having a little trouble getting this working with properties that are created by the mongo store extension.  I end up with a property like 'icon.type'.  However when trying http://localhost/icons/{icon.type}" I get an exception from geoserver: The requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute of icon/type and the layer is: cite:test

Comment: Ah, it's because the . in CQL is interpreted as a path separator and turned internally in "icon/type" Try with ${"icon.type"} instead

Comment: thanks so much for the response.  I did try quoting the string however it needs to be escaped properly in the xml.  Sending this: xlink:href="http://localhost/icons/{&quot;icon.type&quot;}"  with no luck.  Is CQL missing this?  Is there a different way to encode those inner quotes on the href attribute?

Comment: After a little more research (see edit) I do not think that cql is missing this. I think that mongo is being queried incorrectly. Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: You might ask on the geoserver users list and see if any developer active on the mongo community module has a clue. Mind, the module is unsupported and help is provided on a volountary basis, so don't assume you'll get an answer. If worst comes to worst the code is there, or you can look at commercial support providers.

Comment: Good news is its not a problem with the unsupported plugin.  Seems to be a limitation in the way SLD parser handles the CQL in that the value could end up having a character that needs to be URL encoded.  See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200713/dynamic-symbolizers-w-cql-not-url-encoded